# "An" in Shakespeare's Taming of the Shrew

Tags: literature, shakespeare, diction, seventeenth-century-english

In Act 1, Scene 1, Katherine says to Bianca,

> A pretty peat! It is best / Put finger in the eye, an she knew why".

I understand "Put finger in the eye" means she is fake crying for sympathy, but what does "an she knew why" mean?

I'm guessing that "an," somehow means "if," since this makes the most sense.

Comment: It is indeed an old word for 'if' - see  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ifs_and_ans (sometimes misquoted as 'ifs and ands').

Comment: OED: **An** -- **B. n. = and** Chiefly in plural in ifs and ans. ?1697 *If he promises any favour..it is with so many ifs and ans that he seldom fails of finding a backdoor, to evade all his promises.* -- 1850 ‘If a poor man's prayer can bring God's curse down.’.. ‘If ifs and ans were pots and pans.’ -- 1977 Such assessments must necessarily be qualified by a multitude of ifs and ans.

Comment: +1 Excellent question! I wish this had a decent answer :)

Answer (score 2):

In Shakespeare's English, 'an' could be a clipped form of 'and', which had several meanings that have disappeared. See *A Shakespeare Glossary* by C. T. Onions, enlarged and revised by Robert D. Eagleson (Oxford University Press, 1986):

> **and, an, an'**
> (…)
> *sub. conj.*
>
> 1. If; even if, though. [1H4 2.4.283](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/1henryiv/1henryiv.2.4.html): "Ah, no more of that, Hal, an thou lovest me!" (…)

This conjunction is sometimes duplicated, i.e. when Shakespeare writes "and if". See for example Caliban's words in [*The Tempest*, Act 2, scene 2](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/tempest/tempest.2.2.html):

> These be fine things, an if they be not sprites.

Returning to *The Taming of the Shrew*, Katherine is saying, "The best thing she can do is to make herself weep, if she knew of some excuse". (See *The Taming of the Shrew*, edited by G. R. Hibbard. The New Penguin Shakespeare. 1968. Page 181.)